# How would I fix the moving position exactly to the part I want it to move?

Tags: modeling

[image: **enter image description here**]

See how on the image the positioning isn't correct. I'm talking about the white pieces see how far they are from those movers with arrows that means If I move I would have to move an extra. It also makes it impossible for me to rotate them to the exact way I want without spending 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

in blender every object has an object origin the transform manipulators are at the pivot point and the pivot point is at the object origin (you can change where the pivot point is), if you want to move the object origin go to the Object>Transform menu there you have a couple of options, origin to geometry should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: or shortcut shift ctrl alt C, and in 2.8 it will be Object > Set Origin